# How to write the script to plot only the buy MACD signals when SMA 50 crossabove SMA 200

Tags: filter, pine-script

I have similiar strategies to plot only MACD buy signals on chart when SMA50 above SMA200. Unfortunately, it prompted me error:

```
"line 31: Mismatched input 'MACD_buy' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'
```

This is my code:

```
//@version=4
study("Testing MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD

// EMA or SMA input //

len50 = input(50, minval=1, title="SMA 50")
len200 = input(200, minval=1, title="SMA 200")

src50 = input(close, title="SMA 50 Source")
src200 = input(close, title="SMA 200 Source")

sma50 = sma(src50, len50)
sma200 = sma(src200, len200)

//aboveEMA10 = ema10 > ema20
//belowEMA10 = ema10 < ema20

//barcolor(aboveEMA10 ? color.olive : na)

plot(sma50, color=color.blue, linewidth=3, title="SMA 50")
plot(sma200, color=color.red, linewidth=4, title="SMA 200")


if sma50 > sma200
MACD_buy = crossover(delta, 0)
plotshape(MACD_buy, title='MACD BUY', style=shape.triangleup, 
text='B', location=location.belowbar, color=#00BCD4, 
textcolor=color.gray, size=size.tiny)

if sma50 < sma200
MACD_sell = crossunder(delta, 0)
plotshape(MACD_sell, title='MACD SELL', style=shape.triangledown, 
text='S', location=location.abovebar, color=#E040FB, 
textcolor=color.gray, size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift line 31 and 35 by 4 spaces or 1 time press tab when you use IF FUNCTION. Note you can not use plotshape with if function. I corrected the code.

You can delete line 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36 (not required inside code, however I left them so you can see the 4 spaces)

You can see code working here, https://www.tradingview.com/x/KPz31eWv/

```
//@version=4
study("Testing MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD
zeroline = input(0)
// EMA or SMA input //

len50 = input(50, minval=1, title="SMA 50")
len200 = input(200, minval=1, title="SMA 200")

src50 = input(close, title="SMA 50 Source")
src200 = input(close, title="SMA 200 Source")

sma50 = sma(src50, len50)
sma200 = sma(src200, len200)

//aboveEMA10 = ema10 > ema20
//belowEMA10 = ema10 < ema20

//barcolor(aboveEMA10 ? color.olive : na)

plot(sma50, color=color.blue, linewidth=3, title="SMA 50")
plot(sma200, color=color.red, linewidth=4, title="SMA 200")


if sma50 > sma200
    MACD_buy = crossover(delta, 0)
    //plotshape(MACD_buy, title='MACD BUY', style=shape.triangleup, text='B', location=location.belowbar, color=#00BCD4, textcolor=color.gray, size=size.tiny)

if sma50 < sma200
    MACD_sell = crossunder(delta, 0)
    //plotshape(MACD_sell, title='MACD SELL', style=shape.triangledown, text='S', location=location.abovebar, color=#E040FB, textcolor=color.gray, size=size.tiny)
    
    
buy = sma50 > sma200 and crossover(delta, 0)
sell = sma50 < sma200 and crossunder(delta, 0)

plotshape(buy, title='MACD BUY', style=shape.triangleup, text='B', location=location.belowbar, color=#00BCD4, textcolor=color.gray, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title='MACD SELL', style=shape.triangledown, text='S', location=location.abovebar, color=#E040FB, textcolor=color.gray, size=size.tiny)
```