# pinescript coding buy only over 200ma

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

i have RSI strategy which buys when oversold.
is there a way to code that only submits buy order if stock is above 200 ma.
i have taken two courses on pine script but can not work out how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

look at this, done that few days back, similer to your question.

[How to write the script to plot only the buy MACD signals when SMA 50 crossabove SMA 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973488/how-to-write-the-script-to-plot-only-the-buy-macd-signals-when-sma-50-crossabove/68976062#68976062)

Comment: thank you yes,quite similar, but i need price to be above 200 sma as a filter whether too buy or not.